# Meter datos en Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

tengo problemas con Laravel framework.

Mi problema es que por alguna razón, cuando intento meter datos de una forma, estos no se envían y manda un error 404 "page not found".

Este es el codigo que tengo.

web (En la carpeta routes):

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
 });

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/home/sendData', 'HomeController@sendData')->name('home/sendData');
```

HomeController (En la carpeta controllers):

```
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
public function sendData(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'nombre'    =>  'required',
        'precio'     =>  'required',
        'empresa'     =>  'required'
    ]);

    $product = new product([
        'nombre'    =>  $request->get('nombre'),
        'precio'     =>  $request->get('precio'),
        'empresa'     =>  $request->get('empresa')
    ]);
    $product->save();
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Data Added');
}
```

home.blade (En la carpeta views):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                @if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                @endif

                Has iniciado sesion
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<br />
<h3>Meter datos del producto</h3>
<br />
<form method="post" action="{{url('home')}}">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="form-group" align="center">
<input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Coloque el nombre del producto" />
</div>
<div class="form-group" align="center">
<input type="number" name="precio" class="form-control" placeholder="Coloque el precio" />
</div>
<div class="form-group" align="center">
<input type="text" name="empresa" class="form-control" placeholder="Coloque el nombre de la empresa" />
</div>
<div class="form-group" align="center">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Esta es mi base de datos. Quiero que se conecte a products

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.3
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 20-10-2018 a las 23:00:35
-- Versión del servidor: 10.1.36-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 7.2.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `lava_prueba`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `migrations`
--

CREATE TABLE `migrations` (
`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`migration` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`batch` int(11) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `migrations`
--

INSERT INTO `migrations` (`id`, `migration`, `batch`) VALUES
(1, '2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table', 1),
(2, '2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table', 1),
(3, '2018_10_13_032430_create_products_table', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `password_resets`
--

CREATE TABLE `password_resets` (
`email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`token` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `products`
--

CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`producto` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`precio` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`empresa` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `migrations`
--
ALTER TABLE `migrations`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `password_resets`
--
ALTER TABLE `password_resets`
ADD KEY `password_resets_email_index` (`email`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `products`
--
ALTER TABLE `products`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `migrations`
--
ALTER TABLE `migrations`
MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `products`
--
ALTER TABLE `products`
MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `users`
 --
 ALTER TABLE `users`
 MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
 COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás enviando el formulario a la action incorrecta.

Error

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('home')}}">
```

Debes apuntarlo a la ruta donde quieres enviar los datos

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('home/sendData')}}">
```

Recomiendo que le quites el slash al nombre dejalo como "home_sendData".

Saludos